# erlang rabbitmq client pool

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, amqp, pool

I need to communicate with RabbitMQ from many Erlang processes.
Looks like opening connection per process is not a good idea.
Is there a good amqp_client pool implementation or at least a worker, which could be started under supervisor?

Answer (score 1):

I think https://github.com/devinus/poolboy will do the trick. It is not rabbitmq-specific pool, though still makes life a lot easier.

Comment: But, as been answered in your previous answer - channels much better way to start with. You don't need multiple connections, usually.

Comment: Sure, it's clear with channels. I'm just surprised, that there is no pool for rabbitmq clients. It should be quite a common task. I will opensource once I have something.

Comment: Well, it takes fifteen minutes to mock up one using poolboy and it is so for almost any resource you can think of, not only for rabbitmq connections.